# Django URL error when using forms

Tags: python, django

I am fairly new to Django and I am totally stuck on what is causing this error. I have done lots of searching but to no avail! Any help would be super appreciated.

The actual form works fine but when I try and submit the input data I get the error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^$ [name='home']
^patientlist [name='patient_list']
^patientdetail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$ [name='patient_detail']
^add_patient/$ [name='add_patient']

The current URL, spirit3/add_patient/, didn't match any of these.
```

My urls.py in the mysite directory looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'', include('spirit3.urls')),
]
```

My urls.py in the app looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'), 
url(r'^patientlist', views.patient_list, name='patient_list'), 
url(r'^patientdetail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.patient_detail, name='patient_detail'), 
url(r'^add_patient/$', views.add_patient, name='add_patient'),
]
```

The relevant part of views.py:

```
def add_patient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = PatientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = PatientForm()
    return render(request, 'spirit3/add_patient.html', {'form':form})
```

And the html looks like:

```
{% extends 'spirit3/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<body>
    <h1> Add a Patient </h>
    <form action="/spirit3/add_patient/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create Patient" />
    </form>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Just because the app is called `spirit3` doesn't mean the url uses it. you could change the action to be just `/add_patient/` although Im not sure which fix you're looking for, you may want to change the url that includes the spirit3 urls (think of it as string concatenation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the form "action" attribute is wrong... seeing your urls configuration you dont have a `/spirit3/add_patient/` url, I think It is `/add_patient/`

or you could just use a form tag without an "action" it will post to the current page:

```
<form role="form" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" value="Create Patient" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As pleasedontbelong mentionned, there's indeed no url matching "/spirit3/add_patient/" in your current url config. What you have in tour root urlconf is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('spirit3.urls')),
]
```

This means that urls with path starting with "/admin/" are routed to `admin.site.urls`, and all other are routed to `spirit3.urls`. Note that this does NOT in any way *prefixes* urls defined in `spirit3.urls` with '/spirit3/', so in your case, all of these urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'), 
    url(r'^patientlist', views.patient_list, name='patient_list'), 
    url(r'^patientdetail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.patient_detail,      name='patient_detail'), 
   url(r'^add_patient/$', views.add_patient, name='add_patient'),
   ]
```

will be served directly under the root path "/" - ie, the `add_patient` view is served by "/add_patient/", not by "/spirit3/add_patient/".

If you want your `spirit3` app's urls to be routed under "/spirit3/*", you have to specify this prefix in your root urlconf, ie:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^spirit3/', include('spirit3.urls')),
]
```

Note that you can use any prefix, it's totally unrelated to your app name.

As a last note: never hardcode urls anywhere, django knows how to reverse an url from it's name (and args / kwargs if any). In a template you do this with the [`{% url %}` templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url), in code you use [`django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Comment: Thanks Bruno! That makes sense now. Appreciate the help

Comment: @KirstyRussell glad I could help. And if I did, please feel free to  upvote my answer ;)